# cppyy pass array to the C++ function from python

Tags: pypy

I used the C++ to write a simple sort function,its declare is void sort(int *, int)
I use the cppyy the use the C++ extension in the python function,the document tell me I can use the array.array when I need to pass the builtin data pointer types.
But it always prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "app_main.py", line 51, in run_toplevel

  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>

    m.sort(ai, 1)

TypeError: none of the 1 overloaded methods succeeded. Full details:

  void MyClass::sort(int*, int) =>

    TypeError: no converter available
```

This is the python code I write:

```
#coding=utf8
import cppyy
import time
from array import array

cppyy.load_reflection_info("libMyClassDict.so")

MyClass = cppyy.gbl.MyClass
m = MyClass()
start = time.time()

m = MyClass()

for i in xrange(10000000):
    ai = array('i', [23])
    m.sort(ai, 1)
    m.SetMyInt(312, 2315, 2135, 13, 3251, 54, 2134, 3253, 134, 3251);

end = time.time()
print end - start
```

Anyone can solve my problem?